# How to get FlatBufferToString to generate valid JSON for union types?

Tags: flatbuffers

I have a union type in my flatbuffers schema:

```
union Quux { Foo, Bar, Baz }
table Root {
   quux: Quux
}
```

If I convert to json using flatc, it looks like this:

```
{
  quux_type: "Bar",
  quux: {...}
}
```

But if I use `FlatBufferToString` from `flatbuffers/minireflect.h`, then I get this instead, which is not valid JSON.

```
{ 
  quux_type: Bar,
  quux: {...},
}
```

I'm calling flatc like this

```
flatc --reflect-names --cpp -o include src/quux.fbs
```

How can I get minireflect to produce valid json output for union types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the comment: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/4e45f7c9e8da64a9601eeba1231079c3ce0a6dc2/include/flatbuffers/minireflect.h#L282 the minireflect string conversion is very simple, and only trying to be JSON-alike.

That said, if you pass `true` to the `tostring_visitor` in https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/4e45f7c9e8da64a9601eeba1231079c3ce0a6dc2/include/flatbuffers/minireflect.h#L396-L404 it looks like you will get quotes both around the enum value and the field names.